# Underscore 1.6 templates, allowed operators

Tags: templates, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Using custom tags in (Wordpress packaged) Underscore 1.6, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
{| if (1 < 2) print('success') |}
```

Here's the Underscore custom config:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate : /\{\|(.+?)\|}/g,
};
```

Whenever I use `<` or `>` operators, I get the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

But if I use `==` everything's ok. Why?
Is there some restriction on operators I'm unaware of?

Comment: That works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wa6ao0o9/). What does your template really look like? Also, it is a good idea to supply all three `_.templateSettings` regexes to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found out the problem : I used .innerHTML function to retrieve my template content and it was converting some characters to html entities : "<" being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since my template was an actual HTML element, retrieving the template code using innterHTML returned a string with html entities encoded. The solution was simple :
 `var template = _.template(_.unescape(this.el.innterHTML))`.

Comment: Or better, store your templates in `<script type="text/x-underscore">` containers since they're rarely valid HTML.